# Reduce multiple columns into one using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have several columns in a DataFrame that I would like to combine into one column:

```
from functools import reduce # python 3.x
na=pd.np.nan
df1=pd.DataFrame({'a':[na,'B',na],'b':['A',na,na],'c':[na,na,'C']})
print(df1)
     a    b    c
0  NaN    A  NaN
1    B  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN    C
```

The output I am trying to get is supposed to look like (column name doesn't matter):

```
  a
0 A
1 B
2 C
```

I get `ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values` when I run this line of code:

```
reduce(lambda c1,c2: df1[c1].fillna(df1[c2]),df1.loc[:,'a':'c'])
```

However, it seems to work when I change the `sequence` argument of `reduce` to just two columns `df1.loc[:,'a':'b']`:

```
reduce(lambda c1,c2: df1[c1].fillna(df1[c2]),df1.loc[:,'a':'b'])
0      A
1      B
2    NaN
Name: a, dtype: object
```

I've also tried to use the DataFrame/Series `.combine` method, but that produces the same error. **I would like to try to get this working in case I ever want to fill non-nan values**:

```
reduce(lambda c1,c2: df1[c1].combine(df1[c2],(lambda x,y: y if x==pd.np.nan else x)),df1.loc[:,'a':'c'])
```

I don't think this is working like I am hoping though, because when I again restrict to just two columns I get this output:

```
reduce(lambda c1,c2: df1[c1].combine(df1[c2],(lambda x,y: y if x==pd.np.nan else x)),df1.loc[:,'a':'b'])
0    NaN
1      B
2    NaN
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use sum over axis 1

```
df1.fillna('').sum(1)

0    A
1    B
2    C
```

Option2: use bfill and pick the first column

```
df1.bfill(axis = 1).iloc[:, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

this also works :

```
pd.DataFrame(data=df.stack().values, index=df.index, columns=['a'])
```

Results :

```
    a
0   A
1   B
2   C
```